# Checking string to categorize items in Python

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to categorize string variable based on the value from other variable.

For example:

```
line ='Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak]'
key = 'Centrino Advanced'
key2 ='Centrino'
```

when I execute

```
print(all(word in line.lower() for word in key.lower().split()))
print(all(word in line.lower() for word in key2.lower().split()))
```

they both return true, of course, but I want it to just match the ***key*** instead both ***key*** and ***key2***

I want it to be outputted like below, which consider key2 is not valid.
What would be the best approach to perform such task?

```
line ='Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak]'
key = 'Centrino Advanced'  # True
key2 ='Centrino' # False
```

Thank you all in advanced.

Comment: Why should it return False for `key2`?

Comment: Are you sure you understand why those two lines return `true`?

Comment: I want to categorize the item based on my key. In this example the line should belong to 'Centrino Advanced' not 'Centrino'

Comment: @BallpointBen because they both has the word 'Centrino' ? Hope I get it right. If not, could you please spell it out for me?

Comment: So given that's the case, why should `key2` not work?

Comment: Is it possible for a line to have both? Like, both should actually be true?

Comment: @Kewl in my case, I don't want both of them to be true so I can categorize the string belong to 'Centrino Advanced', not 'Centrino'

Comment: How are you making this determination? Should 'trapdoor' match 'trap' or 'door' or both?

Comment: @BallpointBen, maybe I came to the wrong direction. But, is it possible to perform such task, which could do exact match?

Comment: Is my answer not what you're looking for?

Comment: @Kewl your answer is good, but the **key** has to follow the sequence of order. what if I swap **key1** and **key2**. it will give me something differnet

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for, then. Do you want a function that takes two keys, one of which may contain the other? It would be easy to wrap what I wrote in a function that figures out if one contains the other first. Or do you have a list of keys?

Answer (score 0):

You can just get rid of the substring of the other key in the string by using replace:

```
string = 'Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak]'
key1 = 'Centrino Advanced'
key2 = 'Centrino'

print(key1 in string)
print(key2 in string.replace(key1, ''))

True
False
```